# PHP Curl Login Cookies

Tags: php, cookies, curl

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
I can't use real URL's so I would use site A.com and B.com

1. From page A.com I display a login form, then I use CURL to submit the values to domain B, login and get the cookie name
2. Then I set the headers with correct info and cookie name
3. Redirect the page to B.com/welcome.php using PHP location function

My problem is that I always get the error : Your session has expired. Please login again.
If I use CURL to login and get the cookie and then use CURL to display the page it works.

The CURL part works fine, the following code causes the session expired error"

```
header ('Host: B.com\n');
header ('User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1\n');
header ('Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\n');
header ('Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5\n');
header ('Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\n');
header ('Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\n');
header ('Referer: http://B.com/\n');
header ('Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n');
header ('location: B.com/welcome.php');
```

The reason I'm using those headers is because that's exactly what is sent from Firefox when I manually login into the page.

Thanks for your help

Comment: You can't set cookies *for* site B.com from A.com. Cookies can only be set for any given domain by that domain. There is no work-around for this. Almost all browsers will block [third-party cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#Third-party_cookie) by default, and this would need to be explicitly allowed by the client.

Comment: I can't help but suspect that this will be used for nefarious purposes.

Comment: I'm not trying to set third parties cookies, I create the cookie via curl, get the cookie value and then pass the value via location, so in theory, the PHP server should read the cookie value and say I have a session with that id please go on...

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, your browser does not have the same cookie store that curl uses and so when the page checks for cookie information from the browser it will not find what it is expecting. If you want this login to work in the browser, you will need to set the cookies in the browser BEFORE directing to the welcome page.